# Romania single entry visa

Tags: romania, bulgaria

1. Assuming my visa is approved for Romania visa single entry, Am I allowed to travel to Bulgaria? or is it only for multiple entries?
2. Can I just go directly to Bulgaria without entering Romania?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer to both questions is *no*. You would need a multiple entry visa *and* to have already entered the issuing country.

You can confirm this on the [IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/) website by inputting the details of the proposed trip.

Also:

> As from 21 April 2023  the holders of valid double or multiple entry visas issued by Cyprus and Romania have the right to enter in the Republic of Bulgaria only if the said  visa has been used at least once to enter in the issuing country.

Source: http://bulgarianembassy-london.org/consular-services/visas/